# hiding a specific flex child when both children have a width of 100vw

Tags: html, css

If both my children have a `width: 100vw;` and my parent is set to flex which puts them side by side. I can control which child renders first with `flex-direction: row-reverse;` but how can I hide the child element that is not currently on the screen.

I have tried setting the parent's width to `width:100vh;` but that compresses the two children together, and also setting the parent's width to `width:200vh;` with `overflow: hidden;` does not solve my problem as well

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child-one'/>
    <div class='child-two'/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
   display: flex;
   width: // ??
}


.child-one,
.child-two {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to be full width, set the flex container to have a `flex-wrap: wrap;`

```css
.parent{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   width: 100%;
}


.child-one,
.child-two {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: navy;;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child-one'></div>
    <div class='child-two'></div>
</div>
```

If you want to hide one, use `display: none;`

```css
.parent{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   width: 100%;
}


.child-one,
.child-two {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: navy;;
}

.child-one {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child-one'></div>
    <div class='child-two'></div>
</div>
```